# How to use JFrog artifact repository in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, repository, artifactory

Please let me know how I could use/import/download a tool from JFrog artifact repository to my Maven project. I have not worked with artifactory before and Googling did not help much so any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start with the [Working with Maven](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Maven) section in the Artifactory [user guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Welcome+to+Artifactory)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with a Jfrog Artifactory from your maven project you need to:

- Create maven repos in Jfrog Artifactory.

  I recomend you to create a local SNAPSHOT repo and a local release repo for every type of maven repo that you want.

  Example of local repos:

  ```
  libsrepo-snapshot-local 
  libsrepo-release-local
  projectsrepo-snapshot-local
  projectsrepo-local-local
  ```

  You can create a remote repo for external dependencies, for example, for maven central.

  Example of remote repo:

  ```
  maven-remote
  ```

  Also, you can create a virtual repo to agrupe all your maven repo. For example, you can create the repo "maven-virtual-repo" where you can have all the repos that you want.

  Example of virtual repo:

  ```
  maven-virtual-repo
  ```
- Configure your settings.xml to work with your Jfrog Artifactory repos. You can get more info here: [How to configure your settings.xml to work with repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-ManuallyOverridingtheBuilt-inRepositories)
- Deploy to Jfrog Artifactory using:

  ```
  mvn deploy
  ```

If you need more help about how to create repos in Jfrog Artifactory you can visit the official guide: [Configuring Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories)